# Parameter is invalid, when I replace a bmp into PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, bmp

I want to replace `PictureBox.Image` with a new `bmp`.Like these:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp); 
g1.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
PbDm3.Image = bmp;
if(bmp != null)
{
    bmp.Dispose();
}
```

But it will tell me `Parameter is invaild`.

Tips:
I tried add Garbage collection by myselef, it's not useful.

I want to know why is it happened, and how to fix it.

Comment: You have to dispose of the previous Image assigned to the PictureBox, if any, not the current. E.g., `PbDm3.Image?.Dispose(); PbDm3.Image = bmp;`. Also you really need to dispose of the Graphics object -- The current can be disposed when the parent Form closes

Comment: I don't need  `PbDm3.Image?.Dispose();`,cause there is no image in the beginning.@Jimi
I'll add `g1.Dispose();`.

Comment: *I want to replace PictureBox.Image*: then, there's an Image you want to replace. Since *initially* there's none, that's the reason why you see `PbDm3.Image?.Dispose()` and not `PbDm3.Image.Dispose()`. See the [Null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) (a.k.a. the Elvis Operator), in case you don't know what that means

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code because when you dispose the bmp, the picture will be lost

```
if(bmp != null)
{
    bmp.Dispose();
}
```

---

After use Graphics class, Dispose this

```
Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp); 
g1.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
g1.Dispose();
```

Or

```
using (Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g1.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
}
```

Comment: You have to dispose of the Bitmap. Read my comments on the question